# Author name and user fields when packaging magento extension

Tags: extensions, user, package, name

**I am echoing an unanswered question here.**

What exactly goes in the 3 fields displayed on in the Magento packaging guide "Section C:  Authors"?   The guide has a screenshot that includes 3 fields, **Name**, **User**, and **Email** and specifically instructs me to enter the "User Name" from my MagentoCommerce.com account.

When I login to my Magentocommerce.com account and click "MY ACCOUNT" - there is NO user name field.   There is only my **First Name**, **Last Name**, **Email**, and **Screen Name** (which I am not to use per online wiki).

It is very unclear what exactly is to go in the NAME field and the USER field in the packaging section.

Thank you!